# How to read alert message using Firefox Driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I need to read alert & confirmation messages displayed in pop ups using java and print it on the console. On export of the selenium recording from the IDE as a *Junit4* (WebDriver) java file, my code is:

```
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

Now when I tried to use `getAlert` or `getConfirmation` functions as shown:

```
@Test
public void testSample() throws Exception {
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
message = alert.getText();
System.out.println("message is "+message);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.tests.Sample.testSample(Sample.java:40)
at com.example.tests.Sample.main(Sample.java:149)
Exception: null
```

How do I handle this? Also is there any other way of reading the pop up messages?

Answer (score 5):

In the testSample() method when you navigate to any page by using -

```
driver.get("URL");
```

After that can you explain how the alert message comes up in the 1st place.

Are you sure that the pop up message which appears is a `javascript alert` or any window which is opening up.

If it is a an alert message then you can access it by using -

```
driver.switchTo().alert();
```

But if the pop up is another window then you will have to use -

```
driver.switchTo().window("windowName");
```

You can get more information about this from [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/NextSteps#Moving_Between_Windows_and_Frames).